# Why are the random exponents so much bigger in the Socialist Millionaire protocol versus Diffie-Hellman key exchange?

Tags: authentication, diffie-hellman, keys

Section 8, Security considerations, of [RFC3526](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3526.txt), which defines groups used for Diffie-Hellman has a table recommending some random exponent sizes. In particular, it says:

- The strength of a key exchanged using the 1536 bit group has

  - about 90 bits strength for a 180 bit random exponent
  - about 120 bits of strength for a 240 bit random exponent

On the other hand, the [Off-the-Record protocol](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/Protocol-v2-3.1.0.html) spec, which uses that 1536 bit DH group, says:

> The random exponents are 1536-bit numbers.

I'm not adhering to the OTR spec, because I'm just using the SMP part of it. But I'm interested to find out:

What is the reason to use these comparatively huge random exponents, when a DH key exchange gets what I would call "enough" strength at far lower exponent sizes? I'm interested because 240 bit random numbers make the authentication go a lot quicker.

As a bonus: how does SMP using the 2048, or 4096 bit groups with smaller random exponents compare to using the 1536 bit group with large random exponents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**For Diffie-Hellman**, adequate security is achieved provided that:

- we work modulo a prime $p$ big enough to resist discrete logarithm (1536 bits are sufficient);
- the order of the subgroup generated by $g$ is a multiple of a big-enough prime integer $q$ ($q$ should have length $2n$ bits to achieve $2^n$ security);
- the private exponents are randomly chosen in a big enough range ($2n$-bit exponents to reach $2^n$ security).

The first two conditions are necessary for the discrete logarithm to be hard. But having hard discrete logarithm is not necessarily *sufficient* for the security of the cryptographic algorithm which uses that group. Diffie-Hellman appears to be reasonably secure with the conditions above. However, other protocols require a bit more. A prime example is [DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm). With DSA, you work in a subgroup of size $q$ (a prime integer) generated by a conventional value $g$ modulo a big prime $p$; whenever you sign, you select a random $k$ modulo $q$ (that's a "secret exponent"). $k$ **must** be chosen uniformly in the $[1...q-1)]$ range; simply choosing a "big enough" $k$ is not sufficient: any bias in the selection of $k$ can be exploited to rebuild the private key from the observation of several signatures (many signatures, if the bias is slight).

So your question is: is SMP more like Diffie-Hellman, i.e. tolerates that private exponents be chosen in a subrange, or more like DSA, for which uniform selection in the whole range is necessary ? Barring any explicit indication to the contrary, it is safer to assume that uniform selection in the whole range should be used. In particular, it seems to me that non-uniform selection may imply exploitable biases in the zero-knowledge proofs which are sent along the SMP values.